# MVC List View and models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am receiving this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
>   'Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel', but this dictionary
>   requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel]'.

i have this in my controller

```
public ActionResult MaintenanceCheckList (MaintenanceCheckListModel check)
    {
       List<MaintenanceCheckListModel> checklist = db.checklists.Select( s => new MaintenanceCheckListModel()
        {
            FirstMonth = check.FirstMonth,
            SecondMonth = check.SecondMonth,
            ThirdMonth = check.ThirdMonth,
            FourthMonth = check.FourthMonth,
            FifthMonth = check.FifthMonth,
            SixthMonth = check.SixthMonth,
            SeventhMonth = check.SeventhMonth,
            EighthMonth = check.EighthMonth,
            NinethMonth = check.NinethMonth ,
            TenthMonth = check.TenthMonth,
            EleventhMonth = check.EleventhMonth,
            TwelvethMonth = check.TwelvethMonth
        }).ToList();

        return View(check);

    }
```

and here is my view

```
{
 @model IEnumerable<Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "MaintenanceCheckList";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>MaintenanceCheckList</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SecondMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ThirdMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FourthMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FifthMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SixthMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SeventhMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EighthMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NinethMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TenthMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EleventhMonth)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TwelvethMonth)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecondMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ThirdMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FourthMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FifthMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SixthMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SeventhMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EighthMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NinethMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TenthMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EleventhMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TwelvethMonth)
    </td>

</tr>
}
```

what is the solution to the error?

Comment: as per your code you return MaintenanceCheckListModel instead of IEnumerable<Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel>

Comment: Pass "checklist' instead of "check" to the view

Comment: Remove the `MaintenanceCheckListModel check` parameter from your method and change the return statement to `return View(checklist);`

Answer (score 3):

Change your controller action to following:

```
public ActionResult MaintenanceCheckList (MaintenanceCheckListModel check)
{
       List<MaintenanceCheckListModel> checklist = db.checklists.Select( s => new MaintenanceCheckListModel()
        {
            FirstMonth = check.FirstMonth,
            SecondMonth = check.SecondMonth,
            ThirdMonth = check.ThirdMonth,
            FourthMonth = check.FourthMonth,
            FifthMonth = check.FifthMonth,
            SixthMonth = check.SixthMonth,
            SeventhMonth = check.SeventhMonth,
            EighthMonth = check.EighthMonth,
            NinethMonth = check.NinethMonth ,
            TenthMonth = check.TenthMonth,
            EleventhMonth = check.EleventhMonth,
            TwelvethMonth = check.TwelvethMonth
        }).ToList();

        return View(checklist);
}
```

You are passing parameter as a view model which differs in terms of type.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to type difference.You need to pass the same type to your view.
Change your controller or view according to this

```
MaintenanceCheckListModel check
 return View(check);

 @model Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel
```

or

```
List<MaintenanceCheckListModel> checklist = db.checklists.Select( s => new MaintenanceCheckListModel(){}).ToList();
 return View(checklist);

 @model List<Pms_system.Models.MaintenanceCheckListModel>
```

**Edit:**
On a side note, if you are using `List` or an `Ienumerable` then you would have to loop through all the values in your view.

Comment: `List<MaintenanceCheckListModel>` **is** `IEnumerable<MaintenanceCheckListModel>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes your are right ,updated my answer.

Comment: @Sadaquat It doesn't make sense - you are suggesting changing model to the `MaintenanceCheckListModel ` where he clearly has `foreach` in his view.

Comment: @kamo no I have suggested him two ways if he wants to pupulate a single view model then he can use first case where he would not need a foreach loop, but as his question was about a list , so he can use a second code where he would populate a list using a foreach.

Comment: @kamo actually initially I just read the first tr and didn't see the foreach , so i was not clear about his requirements,so I suggested both the ways whether he need  a list or a single viewmodel,so he can implement according to his requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object of MaintenanceCheckListModel whereas you are expecting IEnumerable. Kindly pass checklist instead of check in View from controller.

Just, change return View(check) to return View(checklist);